# pandas: groupby pandas can't get rid of the False spurious data when filtering by '=='

Tags: pandas

I am trying to group two columns with a filter included (in this case, 'miles' and while I get the values I want, I still also get things I don't want like the data under False. Date under True are correct.

```
df.groupby([df.Account =='miles', 'Period'])['New'].sum()
```

I get an output like this:

```
Account  Period    
False    2019-06-01    169847347.0
         2019-07-01    248598361.0
True     2019-01-01         5651.0
         2019-02-01         5185.0
```

and I want to get rid of the "False". I know that it was something related to grouping it yet into another df but I have tried all possible combinations placing the df in all positions.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: An the input also

Comment: I think you want to filter first then group. Perhaps something like `df[df['Account'] == 'miles'].groupby('Period')['New'].sum()`

Comment: briliant! it worked. Put it as answer I will validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you do `df.Account =='miles'` it creates a pandas series that contains all boolean values (e.g., `[False, True, True, False, etc.]`) and then groups on True and False, which is why index level 0 contains both True and False values. One option is to filter your frame first using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then group.

```
df[df['Account'] == 'miles'].groupby('Period')['New'].sum()
```